# Página inicial do WordPress com estrutura diferenciada

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou convertendo uma template em `HTML` feito com Bootstrap que será usada somente na **Página Inicial** para o formato do WordPress e gostaria de incluir o  *slideshow*.

Em razão de estudos, venho aqui pedir-lhes ajuda para que consiga aplicar os elementos do WordPress de forma que apenas tenha efeito na **Página Inicial**:

#### O código:

```
<?php

/**
 * @link http://amzweb.com.br/
 * @package Arcanjo
 * @subpackage Template_Arcanjo
 * @since Arcanjo Template 1.0
 */



get_header(); ?>



<!-- SLIDER AREA end -->



<!-- BODY CONTENT starts here -->



<!-- PANEL 1 -->

<div class="container pm-containerPadding-top-80 pm-containerPadding-bottom-40">

<div class="row">
<!-- SLIDER AREA -->
<div class="pm-pulse-container" id="pm-pulse-container">
<div id="pm-pulse-loader">
<img src="js/pulse/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="slider loading" />
</div>
<div id="pm-slider" class="pm-slider">
<div id="pm-slider-progress-bar"></div>
<ul class="pm-slides-container" id="pm_slides_container">
<!-- FULL WIDTH slides -->
<li data-thumb="img/slider/1a.jpg" class="pmslide_0">
<img src="img/slider/slide1.jpg" alt="img01" />

                        <div class="pm-holder-bg">
                            <div class="pm-holder">
                                <div class="pm-caption">
                                      <h1><span>unleash</span> your inner <span>strength</span></h1>
                                      <span class="pm-caption-decription">
                                        discover your physical potential with energy fitness
                                      </span>
                                      <a href="about-us.html" class="pm-slide-btn">learn more about us</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li data-thumb="img/slider/2a.jpg" class="pmslide_1"><img src="img/slider/slide2.jpg" alt="img02" />

                        <div class="pm-holder-bg">
                            <div class="pm-holder">
                                <div class="pm-caption">
                                      <h1><span>increase</span> your muscle <span>power</span></h1>
                                      <span class="pm-caption-decription">
                                        learn the secrects of resistance training
                                      </span>
                                      <a href="#" class="pm-slide-btn">View program</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>         

                    </li>

                    <li data-thumb="img/slider/3a.jpg" class="pmslide_2"><img src="img/slider/slide3.jpg" alt="img02" />

                        <div class="pm-holder-bg">
                            <div class="pm-holder">
                                <div class="pm-caption">
                                      <h1><span>going</span> the <span>distance</span></h1>
                                      <span class="pm-caption-decription">
                                        an effective cardio program can take you there
                                      </span>
                                      <a href="#" class="pm-slide-btn">Discover Cardio secrets</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="pm-pulse-arrow"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- SLIDER AREA end -->

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <div class="post-header">

        </div><!--end post header-->

        <div class="entry clear">

          <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

          <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

        </div><!--end entry-->

        <div class="post-footer">

        </div><!--end post footer-->

      </div><!--end post-->

    <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>

    <div class="navigation index">

      <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' ); ?></div>

      <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></div>

    </div><!--end navigation-->

  <?php else : ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<!-- Column 1 -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: São estruturas diferentes, dá muito trabalho fazer isso. E não terá um resultado tão bom quanto fazer um projeto usando bootstrap, usando sublime text para editar as páginas e hospedando na hostinger .  Se tiver um tempo a mais pode estar instalando o yeoman e fazendo projetos com 'página mestra', ao você mudar na página inicial muda em todas as demais, em suma. Se quiser aprender a instalar e usar o yeoman + bootstrap + slider + ... pode estar fazendo esse [Curso de AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQi2ltleQmI&index=13&list=PLEtcGQaT56cgHfdvGguisToK90z321pRl)

Comment: O template foi feito usando bootstrap, acho que você não compreendeu minha dúvida. Por exemplo, a página inicial utiliza alguns elementos html a mais e acredito que não dê tanto trabalho assim pois vejo muitos fazendo. No caso é um slideshow em HTML que penso em deixá-lo estático por enquanto, irei incluí-lo apenas na página inicial, tenho o html e css do mesmo pronto.

Comment: Se você postar a estrutura dos elementos html fica mais fácil de entender. Assim fica subjetivo.

Comment: Reestruturei minha pergunta para melhor entendimento. inclui o html do template e expliquei melhor o que desejo, muito obrigado!

Comment: @user21746 Por favor mantenha o código na questão e use a marcação para organiza-lo na pergunta. Leia isto para entender como formular uma boa questão (e torna-la legivel): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Editada novamente e agora, de forma legível. Desculpe.

Comment: essa pergunta não é uma duplicata pelo seguinte motivo: A outra eu peço suporte em converter o slideshow para wordpress, fazendo com que ele puxe as imagens de destaque de postagens, nessa eu estou pedindo para que me ajudem a colocar o html do slideshow na página inicial sem ter de instalar plugins.

Comment: @user21746 O motivo de estarem considerando duplicata não é porque ambas pedem a mesma coisa ou não, o motivo é que ambas questões pedem coisas que não é bem ligada a programação, mas sim a um problema exclusivo seu, que chega a não ser um *PROBLEMA REAL*, mas sim um problema de falta de conhecimento dessa tecnologia especifica (isso é a duplicata), me perdoe não estou falando por mal. Minha opinião (não fique chateado por favor): Ambas questões não são problema reais e soam como *faz pra mim* (não leve a mal hein). O que você precisa é ter algum conhecimento em HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: Outra coisa, na verdade acho que está não é a duplicata, na verdade a outra é a duplicata. Mas ainda sim ambas não são *problema reais*.

Comment: Esta pergunta está referida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4371/129 Resposta é bem vinda :)